# Nant Fails on File::exists check

Tags: .net, nant

I`m getting a problem in a Nant Build i`m running , 
There is a part where i need to execute a file and then delete it , but only if the file exists , 
But the script keeps failing

****The relevant Script part :****

```
    <do>
        <property name="lessfolder.parent" value="${directory::get-parent-directory(lessfile)}" />
        <property name="lessfolder.parent.parent" value="${directory::get-parent-directory(lessfolder.parent)}" />
        <property name="lessfolder.parent.parent.parent" value="${directory::get-parent-directory(lessfolder.parent.parent)}" />
        <property name="cssfile" value="${path::get-file-name-without-extension(lessfile)}" />
        <property name="sabatfiletest" value="${core.publish}\less\LessSaCompile.bat" />
        <echo file="${sabatfiletest}" append="true">
          call ${less} "${lessfile}" > "${lessfolder.parent.parent.parent}\SA_${cssfile}.css"
        </echo>
      </do>
    </foreach>
    <exec program="${core.publish}\less\LessCompile.bat">
    </exec>
    <sleep seconds="4" />
    <exec program="${core.publish}\less\LessSubDomainCompile.bat">
    </exec>
    <sleep seconds="4" />
    <exec program="${core.publish}\less\LessSaCompile.bat" if="${file::exists(sabatfiletest)}">
    </exec>
    <sleep seconds="4" />
    <delete file="${core.publish}\less\LessCompile.bat" />
    <delete file="${core.publish}\less\LessSubDomainCompile.bat" />
    <delete file="${core.publish}\less\LessSaCompile.bat" if="${file::exists(sabatfiletest)}" />
  </target>
```

****And The Error i`m getting  :****

```
Build Error: NAnt.Core.BuildException
Property evaluation failed. Expression: ${file::exists(sabatfiletest)} ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
in D:\Projects\Integration\Scripts\NAnt\iFOREX.Framework.BuildTFS.xml line: 725 col: 6
   at NAnt.Core.PropertyDictionary.EvaluateEmbeddedExpressions(String input, Location location, Hashtable state, Stack visiting)
   at NAnt.Core.PropertyDictionary.ExpandProperties(String input, Location location)
   at NAnt.Core.Element.AttributeConfigurator.InitializeAttribute(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
   at NAnt.Core.Element.AttributeConfigurator.Initialize()
   at NAnt.Core.Element.InitializeXml(XmlNode elementNode, PropertyDictionary properties, FrameworkInfo framework)
   at NAnt.Core.Element.Initialize(XmlNode elementNode, PropertyDictionary properties, FrameworkInfo framework)
   at NAnt.Core.Element.Initialize(XmlNode elementNode)
   at NAnt.Core.Project.CreateTask(XmlNode taskNode, Target target)
   at NAnt.Core.Target.Execute()
   at NAnt.Core.Project.Execute(String targetName, Boolean forceDependencies)
   at NAnt.Core.Project.Execute()
   at NAnt.Core.Project.Run()
```

Comment: Do you define the `sabatfiletest` property before your `foreach` task?  Perhaps there are no items to loop over, so the property never gets defined.  I can see it potentially throwing this error if you do a `file::exists` on a property that doesn't even exist

Comment: <property name="sabatfiletest" value="${core.publish}\less\LessSaCompile.bat" /> , 

Its defined

Comment: That's the one in the `foreach` task as above in the question.  Or is the exact same one in the script before the `foreach` as well?

Comment: I think its only in the foreach ,

Comment: So is it possible that the `foreach` isn't looping over anything?  If it's possible for that to happen, the property would remain undefined by the time it gets to the `file::exists`.

Comment: You are correct , The loop did not recognize the Parameter , and started to work only when i moved it to the global params of the script , thank you very much for your help

Comment: ok cool.  I'll write it up as an answer

Comment: Thanks :) you got my vote

Answer (score 0):

You usually see this error if the property involved in the expansion has not yet been defined.  From the script posted, it looks like the parameter is being defined within the `<foreach>` task.

You haven't posted the start of the `<foreach>` task or what leads up to it, but I'm guessing that in some circumstances it never enters the loop.  If that's the case, the property will remain undefined after the loop, and will cause this error.

The simple solution is to just define the property to a default value before the loop.  Given it's being used in a `file::exists`, defining it to blank should be fine:

```
 <property name="sabatfiletest" value="" />
```